# How create username not unique in memberships?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

I do not like the default settings of memberships.

I need create email unique and that through it, logged in users.

and the field of user we should not be unique.
how to do it? or the need to create a Provider?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you can simply specify in the MemberhipProvider section of your web.config the param [requiresuniqueemail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.requiresuniqueemail.aspx) to true. This tell the provider to be sure to have only one email.

Comment: if you want to have the login to be the email, than without writing your own implementation of a memebershipprovider, simply modify the register section of your site. Before calling `Membership.CreateUser`, replace the username field with the email inserted by the user.